# How do I check if file upload field is empty?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I have a form that allows my to upload multiple image files. Everything works fine, when I select images to upload. If I try to submit the form without files, I get an error

```
OSError: cannot identify image file <FileStorage: '' ('application/octet-stream')>
```

I would like to be able to check if the field is empty and if so, bypass my save_images function.

Here is my form

```py
class NewPortfolioProject(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Project Name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=50)])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', validators=[
                            DataRequired(), Length(min=1, max=1000)])
    tags = StringField('#Tags - space separated', validators=[DataRequired()])
    link = StringField('Link to live project')
    github_link = StringField('Github link', validators=[DataRequired()])
    images = MultipleFileField('Add screenshots/wireframes', validators=[FileAllowed(['png', 'jpg'])])
    submit = SubmitField('Save Project')
```

In my routes.py file I am trying to test if the MultipleFileField contains data

```py
if form.validate_on_submit():

        if not form.images.data:
            portfolio.insert_one(new_doc)
        else: 
            image_files = save_images(form.images.data)           
            new_doc['images'] = image_files
            portfolio.insert_one(new_doc)
```

But this (and everything else I have tried) doesn't work.

Rather than being empty, form.images.data seems to be a filestorage object. How to I test if it is empty?

Comment: shouldn't you use `if not form.images.data` (i.e. aren't you missing a **not**) ?

Comment: @Derlin Sorry, that was a mistake. I have indeed tried `if not form.images.data` the error returned is the same. I have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Apparently when you call form.images.data on MultipleFileField it returns a list that is never empty, which is why **if form.images.data** check always returns true.

I have eventually solved it using try/except in my image saving method, as in my case the error itself is raised when PIL tries to open the image and process it.

```
def save_image(form_picture):
    random_hex = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_picture.filename)
    picture_fn = random_hex + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(current_app.root_path, 'static/images', picture_fn)
    output_size = (600, 400)
    try:
        i = Image.open(form_picture)
        i.thumbnail(output_size)
        i.save(picture_path)
        return picture_fn
    except:
        return False
```